# Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.C#

Tags: c#

El siguiente codigo retorna un string que almacenara otro codigo que sera usado en un chart, el problema es que solo me funciono una vez, luego cuando actualice los datos y lo ejecute, me salio este error "Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz."

```
    DataTable datos = new DataTable();
    datos.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fecha", typeof(string)));
    datos.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gerdau", typeof(string)));
    datos.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Milo", typeof(string)));
    datos.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Playboy", typeof(string)));


    string linea = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\KxroNxoir\\Documents\\Programacion\\C#\\Inversiones Dec\\Archivos\\Empresa.txt");
    string[] arr = linea.Split(new char[1] { ';' });
    string strDatos = "[['Fecha', 'Gerdau', 'Milo', 'Playboy'],";

    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            datos.Rows.Add(new Object[] { arr[i], Convert.ToInt32(arr[++i]), Convert.ToInt32(arr[++i]), Convert.ToInt32(arr[++i]) });
        }



        foreach (DataRow i in datos.Rows)
        {
            strDatos = strDatos + "[";
            strDatos = strDatos + "'" + i[0] + "'," + i[1] + "," + i[2] + "," + i[3];
            strDatos = strDatos + "],";
        }

        strDatos = strDatos + "]";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strDatos = ex.Message;
    }


    return strDatos;
```

Comment: para iterar porque usas ++i ? eso esta raro, solo lees una unica linea del archivo de texto?

Comment: ¿Has intentando depurar tu código? colocar puntos de interrupción y ver que valores tienen tus datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

si no me equivoco, cuando estás recorriendo el bucle

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
```

en la última iteración, i tendrá el valor de un elemento que no existe, ya que está en base 0.

Creo que lo tendrías que cambiar a esto, para que no te fallase:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Agrega que hay otro problema y es el uso de ++i para leer las posiciones del array. Edita tu respuesta y agrega información sobre ese problema tambien.